# How to invoke a beep from the host application to Zebra Omnii XT15 scanner?

Tags: windows-ce, barcode-scanner

I'm running an application in RDP environment for scanning on Zebra Omnii XT15 MS Windows CE 6.0, OS:12.9.44700.0. How can I invoke a beep on the scanner when an error is received in the application?

The scanner has a beeper and a front speaker. The normal beep tones are routed to the beeper and are loud enough to hear on the production floor. Other Windows .wav sound files are routed through the front speaker, which has very low sound output. Is there any specific code or character which can be used in the application to invoke a beep on the scanner? The beep tones are Good Scan Beep, Bad Scan Beep, Multiple Beep. I've tried increasing the volume on the scanner, browsing the Internet for the problem, and consulting Zebra support.

Thanks!